# How to connect Angular 8 with Mongodb?

Tags: angular, mongodb

I am creating a web application in Angular 8. So I want to connect angular 8 with mongodb for storing and retrieveing data from database.

Ive tried running mongo.exe and mongod.exe but didnt work. I also created connection for port 27017 using Robo 3T but it didnt help.

Comment: you can`t connect client side framework like angular to database directly.what you need is a database layer to connect to database and do the transactions.angular will responsible for send your client side data objects to the db layer.

Comment: MongoDB provides a way to connect with a browser application https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/stitch